# How to install the same application more than once on Android?

Tags: android

I have an application that differs for different languages by resources.

Is there a possibility to install the same application on Android several times?

So, as a result I will have German version, French version, English version of the same program, but each installed as a separate applications with different icons.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this by changing the **package name** (in the `AndroidManifest.xml` file). Not the package name for your Java code - the package name for your APK file defined in the `AndroidManifest.xml`. APK files with different package names are considered completely different applications by Android.

---

Note: if this is for internationalizing your application, you really *should* do it as described [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/resources-i18n.html) by Google.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't. At least not without rewriting the androidmanifest.xml to define different identifiers and icons for each of your version.

Comment: Does that mean that any Singleton class that was incorrectly released can appear to be available in any of this applications?

Comment: I don't think so, as each application is running in it's own process. The only way I see this could occur is when the singleton is acting like an explicitly shared service.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the package name (and icon) for each different language version, if you really wanted to have multiple languages of the same app on the same device.